# ASP.NET Sending email via Exchange Server which server certificate is used?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssl

I am having issues sending email from an ASP.NET application.  I keep getting the error message:

"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Doing research here and on other sites, it seems the certificate being presented is not our public GoDaddy certificate which covers our external domain name when accessing the Exchange 2013 server from the internet side.

Looking in the Exchange Admin centre on the mail server I can see various entries in the "Certificates" section:

Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate (assigned to SMTP)

Microsoft Exchange (assigned to SMTP)

Exchange Delegation Federation (assigned to SMTP, Federation)

GoDaddy Cert (assigned to IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP)

Internal Transport (assigned to IMAP, POP, SMTP)

(all the above certs are Self Signed except the GoDaddy one)

When I send email via ASP.NET using System.NET.Mail which of the above certificates is being used.  I have tried using Port 25, 465 and 587 and all get the same error?

Is there a way I can assign the GoDaddy cert to all the above entries and if I did would it break any of the internal email setup?

Any Help Appreciated.

Siv

Addendum: email sending code:

```
    Private Sub CreatePatrolsEmail(ByRef p As Patrols)

    Dim mailto As New MailAddress("external@email.com")
    Dim mailfrom As New MailAddress("internal@domainname.co.uk")
    Dim message As New MailMessage(mailfrom, mailto), Msg As String = ""
    Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient()
    Dim UserAndPass As New NetworkCredential()
    Dim ReplyAddress As String = ""
    Dim Script = ""
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim BodyText As String = ""

    Try
        message.Subject = "Issue relating to " & p.IssueDescription & "."

        'Mail.SubjectEncoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8

        BodyText = "This email is to bring to your attention the following issue:" & NNL
        BodyText += "Building: " & p.Building & NL
        BodyText += "Location: " & p.Location & NL
        BodyText += "Issue:" & p.IssueDescription & NL
        BodyText += "Additional Information:" & NNL
        BodyText += p.AdditionalInfo & NNL
        BodyText += "Sent from the Logging System." & NL
        BodyText += "Date: " & Now.ToShortDateString & NL
        BodyText += "Time: " & Now.ToShortTimeString

        message.Body = BodyText

        'send the message
        mailClient = New SmtpClient("mail.domainname.co.uk", 587) 'specify the mail server address
        mailClient.EnableSsl = True
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        mailClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("internal@domainname.co.uk", "passwordtext")

        mailClient.Send(message)

    Catch ex As Exception

        PEH("SendEmail", "frmA1Patrols", ex.Message)

    Finally

        mailClient.Dispose()
        message.Dispose()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but you should see what machine name/ip address each of the certificates is bound to.  Then depending on if your application is running on the same machine, same lan or across the internet you will have to choose the correct one and possibly deal with firewalls.

Comment: All the self issued certs have the name servername.domainname.local the GoDaddy one has mail.domainname.co.uk which is the server name I am using in my code. So I am at a loss as to why I am getting the error?

Comment: Is the application running on the same machine as exchange?

Comment: Not on the same machine, but on the same network.  We have a main 2012r2 server for file and print and it runs the IIS website on which I have the asp.net application running.  The SQL Server and Exchange 2013 are running on the 2008 r2 server, both in the same domain.

Comment: You will want to use something like "exchange.domain.local" and that will use the cert attached to that within Exchange.

And what method are you using to create the email and connect to the server?

Comment: @tdinpsp I have added the code I am using to the question.

Comment: Is your machine out on the internet or NATed behind a firewall?  If it is behind a firewall do you have the firewall open on port 587 and redirected to the server?  If you are NATed behind a firewall and the firewall does not have the port open then you cannot use mail.domainname.co.uk, or you must open the firewall.  If the firewall is open, can you use a mail client and connect to the machine using mail.domainname.co.uk with SSL and over port 587?  From what I can see without actually running your code in your environment the code looks ok.

Comment: Both machines are NATed behind a firewall router and ports 25, 465, 587 and 993 are port redirected.  The main 2012r2 server which runs IIS and File and Print is on one IP that resolves to "remote.domainname.co.uk" and the SQL and Exchange 2013 box is on a separate IP that resolves to "mail.domainname.co.uk".  In my code I am using 587, but I did wonder if I should use 25 or 2525 (2525 is not port forwarded currently).

Comment: From your application server use "telnet mail.domainname.co.uk 25" and see if it will connect, you can also try other ports.  My guess is that this will not work.  If so then either your exchange or firewall setup is not correct.

Comment: @tdinpsp - I tried your suggestion and get this:  220 InternalServerName.DomainName.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 11 Oct 2020 11:43:52 +0100  helo
250 InternalServerName.DomainName.local Hello [192.168.20.3]  So it seems to be responding OK unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Note that you tried to telnet to mail.domianname.co.uk but it responded internalservername.domainname.local your Exchange setup is not proper.  I'm not really an exchange expert on how it should be setup.  However an easy thing to try is to try to use internaservername.domainname.local instead in your code where you create the SmtpClient.